# Eclipse - How to generate EJB session bean from existing JPA similiar with netbeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

In netbeans there a feature to generate EJB session bean from existing JPA

in netbeans 8.0 i can do it with

1. Right click on my dynamic web project
2. select New >> other
3. select Enterprise Java Beans >> select Session Bean For Entity Class
4. select my desired class >> then click finish

it will generate EJB class to use as DAO

can i do this in eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you have asked is not possible through eclipse configuration with few clicks or selections.(atleast in 3.7.2 version).
Rather you can try following steps to use your existing project to create session beans:
Create a sample EJB project and copy following meta data from this project into your JPA project:
1. Files from .seetings folder. You need to be careful in updating the folder path, i.e. replace temporary project pats with your target project path.
2. Make sure .project file following contents are copied:
org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature
        org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature

1. Make sure EJB library is selected and incorporated into .classpath. Or you can simply copy paste corresponding entry from your EJB test project.
2. Make sure folder 'ejbModule' is copied from test EJB project to your target project. If you get any eclipse error dialog boxes. Ignore them.
3. Restart eclipse

Now you should be able to create session & message driven beans.